# Azure Synapse Studio Not Loading - Failure to load one or more resources due to server error, error code 500

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

Azure Synapse Studio Not Loading - Failure to load one or more resources due to server error, error code 500

Synapse is not loading anything giving error code 500.
All our development work blocked because of this! No proper documentation also available!

Can some one please help unblock us ?

Sharing below screenshot for reference:

[image]

Comment: Is this in the azure web portal? You need to raise a ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes it is the error i am getting when loading synapse studio.

Comment: Do you have an assigned Synapse RBAC role in the Synapse Studio ?

Comment: @NadineRaiss All I have is "Contributor" access on Synapse workspace. Also, FYI, not just me, everyone else who use the workspace is facing the same! I lost all my code in notebooks. dont' have any other backup :(

Comment: Can you execute this PowerShell command to get all the workspace role assignments? 
Get-AzSynapseRoleAssignment -WorkspaceName $workspaceName

Answer (score 1):

There are two sets of RBAC permissions, one on Synapse applied in the Azure portal and one set within Synapse studio.
I’ve also seen similar errors if your client IP address is blocked in the Networking section.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We dont see any ip being blocked in Networking section. We have allowAll=> 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 :(

Answer (score 0):

Azure Synapse has two layer of security for managing acess control

1. At the resource level which we can configure at portal end
2. Inside synapse studio in manage tab there is security section where you need to add your account as Synapse Administrator role if you need highest level of access on workspace.
   If you are not able to open workspace you can do it via powershell
   New-AzSynapseRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName "Synapse Administrator" -ObjectId "" with other required parameter.

Note: If your synase has managed virtual network enabled then you need to add your public ip first to networking section in resource section and then proceed with pwsh cmdlets